# How to represent a non-mandatory option on a login screen

Tags: design, login

Does the below login form convey that users can log into a default product or that they can specify it manually?

Username and password field have placeholders and no default values. However, the product ID will be treated as optional. I doubt whether the below representation will convey it.

Please suggest an alternative.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

[image: login mockup]

Product ID is prefilled with default and a click on change turns it from a label into a textfield which the user then can edit.

Or you could just prefill the textfield with Default (like in your screenshot but in active, more visible text) and let the users figure out if they want to change it or not.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you wrote that the product ID field is non-mandatory but in your comment to Pectoralis Major's answer you are telling that - due to technical reasons - users must know the product ID before logging in. This is a contradiction and hints to a spec or design failure. 
I know login forms similar to Pectoralis Major's draft which resolve the product ID depending on the user name and display it in the login form. His/her draft looks visually more consistent to me than the other proposal. Can the default or assigned product IDs really not be cached client-side in e.g a cookie to fill in the field quickly?

Comment: By default, the product has 1 unique number, but logically it can be split up into many unique ids. Each unique ids have a login. 

The use-case here is user may able to login into default product, or if they know the logically ID they can type it in and log in.

Answer (score 0):

Your Mockup looks like that "Product-ID" is a textfield and i can enter something in there.

I guess the products available for login are fixed/limited so i would go with something like this, since its clear that the user can choose a different product if he wants.

[image]

Depending on the length of the product names you could make it more clear to the user by changing the label of the Login Button to "Login to default" etc.

Comment: Due to technical reasons, Product ID cannot be fetched before authenticating the user. User must know what product they need or can login into a default one.

Answer (score 0):

If "default" is a value and not a placeholder, then display it as a text in the field. Basically, the input is prefilled with the default value. In your design, the field seems empty.

Answer (score 0):

I assume product id here means different platforms users can log in. You may try matching it with the mental modal. So in the real world what choice we make first - which website or log in? I would keep product id info up in the hierarchy before credentials input field -

[image]

Comment: After testing the design with users, they tend to decide on what they want to view and then login. Your answer came handy. Thanks